node-hid Error: [Error: could not read from HID device]
Hello I try get code from barcode reader
`const HID = require('node-hid');
const devices = HID.devices();

console.log(devices);

// Znajdź swoje urządzenie w liście i użyj jego `vendorId` oraz `productId`
const deviceInfo = devices.find(d => d.vendorId === 1046 && d.productId === 49473);
if (!deviceInfo) {
  console.log("Nie można znaleźć urządzenia");
  process.exit(1);
}

const device = new HID.HID(deviceInfo.path);

device.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('Otrzymano dane:', data);
});

device.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Błąd:', err);
});`

this is my device:
let myDevice = { vendorId: 1046, productId: 49473, path: '\\\\?\\HID#VID_0416&PID_C141#6&34abd2&0&0000#{4d1e556f-11cf-88cb-00111}\\KBD', serialNumber: '', manufacturer: 'BarCode', product: 'WPM USB', release: 0, interface: 0,your text usagePage: 1, usage: 6 },
Hello I try get code from barcode reader code from this device.
I've set everything as admin in Windows 11 and reduced UAC to lowest control, folder of my main.js give all permissions.
Anyone has idea what can problem?
Scanner is HDWR HD44
Sorry I forget to add error: [Error: could not read from HID device]

HID scanners emulate keyboard input, so they cannot be treated as any kind of device. It should be handled by events such as KeyDown/Press/Up or input.

I think there is issue with driver on windows, because why it read nodejs by node-hid on my mac without issues, when using node-hid on windows it push this error

Since the operating systems are different, it is not surprising that the details of how the device is used and its behavior are different. It seems that the problem in question is related to this issue. Error: could not read from HID device #386
